# Spark typed aggregation throws exception?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception, types, aggregation

I'm using spark2.3.1 and scala2.12, referring to this page:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/UserDefinedTypedAggregation.scala

First, here's employee.json file:

```
{"name":"Michael", "salary":3000}
{"name":"Andy", "salary":4500}
{"name":"Justin", "salary":3500}
{"name":"Berta", "salary":4000}
```

Then scala code: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/UserDefinedTypedAggregation.scala
I'm compressing code lines here:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator

object sqlAggregation extends App{
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark sql")
    .set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", System.getProperty("user.dir"))
    .setMaster("local[4]");
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config(conf)
    .getOrCreate()

  case class Employee(name: String, salary: Long)
  case class Average(var sum: Long, var count: Long)

  object MyAverage extends Aggregator[Employee, Average, Double] {
    // A zero value for this aggregation. Should satisfy the property that any b + zero = b
    def zero: Average = Average(0L, 0L)
    def reduce(buffer: Average, employee: Employee): Average = {
      buffer.sum += employee.salary
      buffer.count += 1
      buffer
    }
    def merge(b1: Average, b2: Average): Average = {
      b1.sum += b2.sum
      b1.count += b2.count
      b1
    }

    def finish(reduction: Average): Double = reduction.sum.toDouble / reduction.count
    def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Average] = Encoders.product
    def outputEncoder: Encoder[Double] = Encoders.scalaDouble
  }
  import spark.implicits._
  val ds = spark.read.json("employees.json").as[Employee]
  ds.show()
  // Convert the function to a `TypedColumn` and give it a name
  val averageSalary = MyAverage.toColumn.name("average_salary")
  val result = ds.select(averageSalary)
  result.show()
}
```

But on spark-submit, it gives below exception:

```
18/10/24 19:10:53 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
+-------+------+
|   name|salary|
+-------+------+
|Michael|  3000|
|   Andy|  4500|
| Justin|  3500|
|  Berta|  4000|
+-------+------+

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/TypedColumn;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Encoder;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;
        at sqlAggregation$.delayedEndpoint$sqlAggregation$1(sqlAggregation.scala:51)
        at sqlAggregation$delayedInit$body.apply(sqlAggregation.scala:5)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        ... ...
```

Dont' know where the real problem resides in, as I am trying the official spark example. Anything to fix here?

Comment: Can you execute command and paste results here? spark2-submit --version

Comment: Scala 2.12 is not supported in Spark 2.3

Comment: Thanks, downgrading scala command line version to 2.11 solves the problem